# x86 heap method

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

Im trying to understand what this x86 instruction is doing:

```
 movl %eax, heap(,%rdx,4)
```

This is what I think its doing:

move value in eax to area in memory starting at label heap and displaced bytes from the value in rdx.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Man, do I really hate AT&T syntax.

Comment: AT&T syntax should first be burned with fire. Then nuked from orbit. Burning is obligatory to ensure a long and painful death.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AT&T syntax for memory operands is:

```
%segreg:disp(base,index,scale).
```

So the memory address in the instruction you've shown is (better represented in Intel syntax):

```
heap[rdx*4]
```

So in other words, store the value in `eax` at `rdx`*4 bytes from the beginning of `heap`. From this, we can infer that `heap` is probably an array of 4-byte integers, and `rdx` is a loop counter or index into that array.

In Intel syntax, this would be:

```
mov heap[rdx*4], eax
```

For a comparsion between the syntaxes, see [this page](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm).